# apache.commons.math distributions, get probability greater than 1

Tags: java, apache, math

I use **apache commons math** library for **MixtureMultivariateNormalDistribution**. And it appears that sometimes density() function returns me values that are very much greater than 1. What's it?
My mixture coefficients sum to 1 and my covariance matrices of each NormalDistribution are fine (since MixtureMultivariateNormalDistribution constructor doesn't throw any exception when i create the object) and means are fine too. Dimension is 39. And i have 3 normal distribution in a mixture. Is it some bug or what? Did anyone meet this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cumulative distribution function is indeed something between 0 and 1. The DENSITY function, on the other hand, only has to be greater than or equal to zero; in particular, it is allowed to be greater than 1, so long as its integral (the cdf) is equal to 1.

For example, consider a single Gaussian bump centered at the origin. Its density function is `exp(-1/2*x^2/sigma^2)/sigma/sqrt(2*pi)`. Its greatest value, at the origin, is `1/sigma/sqrt(2*pi)`, so for `sigma < 1/sqrt(2*pi)` (approximately 0.399), the peak is greater than 1.

If you are working with mixture components that have sufficiently small variance, the density can be greater than 1 in neighborhoods of their means.

Comment: Actually, you're right. Thanks. But i don't think that my sigma is much less than 0.399. I get numbers like 12.356E10, so it seems to me that sigma should be very small...I wonder maybe it is so because of covariance matrix? Is it possible that in case of multivariate gaussian i get very big negative value in exp term which leads to very great number in total?

Comment: @Artemik The peak value is a function of the covariance alone, specifically a function of the determinant of the covariance. What is the determinant of the covariance of each of the mixture components?

Comment: Determinants and corresponding mixture coefficients: 1.444262001106584E-79 - 0.95, 1.732013988856631E-89 - 0.02, 2.6719557620345887E24 - 0.03.

Comment: OK, you have two degenerate (zero-volume) components, and one which is enormously broad. My guess is that the parameter fitting process went off the rails. My advice is to try to assign initial values for the parameters which are more reasonable than random values; e.g., let the mean of each component be something like the overall mean of the data plus a random offset (to break symmetry) and let the variance of each component be the overall variance. Also, try working in, say, just 2 dimensions until you get a grip on the fitting process.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you mean by "degenerate", but anyway, what concerns about fitting - i use PCA partition. I divide my data into N clusters, where N=3 (three mixtures) using PCA algorithm. Roughly speaking it works as follows: divide initial cluster into 2 along largest eigenvector and find empirical means for both. Choose one which has larger summary deviation from its mean and continue the process recursively. After i have N=3 clusters i run k-means using means of these clusters as initial ones. (btw: k-means actually doesnt change much already achieved means at this step).

Comment: I tried to say that i alread kinda have initialization using empirical parameters.

Comment: @Artemik That sounds like a reasonable initialization. What are the determinants of the covariances found in the initialization. By the way, by "degenerate" I mean that the covariance and therefore the Gaussian bump associated with it has at least one nearly-zero eigenvalue and therefore occupies a subspace of fewer dimensions than the nominal 39 dimensions. Do the data have identical values for one or more of the dimensions? If so, omit those dimensions. I'll suggest again that you work in just a few dimensions until you get the process working OK.

Comment: The determinants are those that i mentioned above. No, data doesn't have identical values. I'll think about trying with lower dimensions. Im implementing viterbi algorithm (Hidden Markov Models) and there i need to compare probabilities of several mixtures to find maximum one for given observation. So the question is, is it correct to compare such densities where mixtures has different peaks and that are (as i said) may be above 1? Or i should maybe normalize this somehow? I'm asking because if i can just compare them as they are, then i don't have to bother about problem of this topic at all.

Comment: @Artemik Assuming that the mixture densities are a reasonable model (I'll let you be the judge of that), comparing values isn't any problem, even if there are very large or very small. Maybe it would help to work with logarithms of probabilities.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your contribution. I'll consider this topic closed.

Answer (score -1):

"Returns the probability density function (PDF) of this distribution evaluated at the specified point x. In general, the PDF is the derivative of the cumulative distribution function. If the derivative does not exist at x, then an appropriate replacement should be returned, e.g. Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.NaN, or the limit inferior or limit superior of the difference quotient."

Does that help?  I presume you're getting the limit superior of the difference quotient.  Unfortunately I don't know what that means.

Comment: Yes, i've read that extract in javadocs. Apparently, this is it. I wonder if anyone know the soultion for this problem.

Comment: The density function of a Gaussian mixture exists everywhere, so the business about limits doesn't come into play. That's presumably the documentation for a base class (or else it is needlessly generalized).

Comment: Indeed, it is from the base-class, MixtureMultivariateRealDistribution, and indeed, a normal distribution curve should limit out at 0.  But if a PDF is the chance that a variable happens to be a value, how can it be > 1?

Comment: `integral(pdf(x), x, S)` is the probability that `x` is in the set `S`. This integral must be less than or equal to 1. But `pdf(x)` is only required to be nonnegative. Values of `pdf(x)` greater than 1 are allowed, so long as the integral is less than or equal to 1 for all `S`. An approximate paraphrase is to say that the peaks of `pdf(x)` can be taller than 1, so long as they are not too wide.

Comment: Ok, so the integral must add up to <= 1, but the curve can go above 1.  So is PDF just on an arbitrary scale, so long as its relative to the rest of the curve?